# Haskell - Implementing Interpreter For the Given Language?

Tags: haskell

I had just started taking Haskell class and in one of my assignment, I need to define the interpreter for the given language, my interpreter managed to read the input but still get the output wrong, I couldn't figure out how to solve the issue from the given test case, perhaps any Haskell wizard can help me figure it out.

The test cases that were given is `interpret "(- 4)"` where the expected output is `-4.0`
and another test case is `interpret "(/ 2)"` where the expected output is `0.5`

When I try to run these two test cases, I got:

```
*Pluto1> interpret "(/2)"
2.0
*Pluto1> interpret "(-4)"
4.0
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
module Pluto1 where

data Token = OpenParen
           | CloseParen
           | Operator Char
           | PosNum Double
     deriving (Show, Eq)

data ParseTree = NumNode Double
               | OpNode Char [ParseTree]
         deriving Show

scan :: String ->[Token]
scan xs
     | null lexeme = []
     | c == '(' = OpenParen:scan rest
     | c == ')' = CloseParen:scan rest
     | elem c ['+', '-', '*', '/'] = Operator c: scan (cs ++ rest)
     | elem c ['0'..'9'] = PosNum (read (c:cs):: Double):scan rest
     | otherwise = error ("Lexical Error - invalid character: " ++ [c])
     where [(lexeme, rest)] = lex xs
           c:cs = lexeme

recognize :: [Token] -> Bool
recognize ts = let (s, r) = rexpr ts
     in s && null r


-- <expr> ->OPENPAREN OPERATOR <operands> CLOSEPAREN |  POSNUMBER
rexpr :: [Token] -> (Bool, [Token])

rexpr (OpenParen:Operator  _: rest) = let(b1,r1) = roperands rest
     in case r1 of
          CloseParen:r2 -> (b1, r2)
          _ ->  error "Parse Error: expected closing parenthesis"

rexpr (PosNum _:rest) = (True, rest)
rexpr x = error $ "Parse Error: invalid expression" ++ (show x)

-- <operands> ->  <expr> [<operands>]
roperands :: [Token] -> (Bool, [Token])
roperands ts = let (b1, r1) = rexpr ts
     in case isValidStart r1 of
          True -> let (b2, r2) = roperands r1 in (b1 && b2, r2)
          False     -> (b1, r1)

isValidStart :: [Token] -> Bool
isValidStart (OpenParen: _) = True
isValidStart (PosNum _:_) = True
isValidStart _ = False

check:: String -> Bool
check = recognize.scan

parse :: [Token] -> ParseTree
parse x = let (pt, ts) = expr x
     in case ts of
          [] -> pt
          _ -> error $ "Parse Error - extra tokens: " ++ (show ts)

-- <expr> ->OPENPAREN OPERATOR <operands> CLOSEPAREN |  POSNUMBER
expr :: [Token] -> (ParseTree, [Token])
expr (OpenParen:Operator c: rest) = let(p1,r1) = operands rest
     in case r1 of
          CloseParen:r -> (OpNode c p1, r)
          _ ->  error "Parse Error: expected closing parenthesis"
expr (PosNum x:rest) = (NumNode x, rest)
expr x = error $ "Parse Error: invalid expression" ++ (show x)         

-- <operands> ->  <expr> [<operands>]
operands :: [Token] -> ([ParseTree], [Token])
operands ts = let (p1, r1) = expr ts
     in case isValidStart r1 of
          True -> let (p2, r2) = operands r1 in (p1 : p2, r2)
          False     -> (p1:[], r1)

stringToTree:: String -> ParseTree
stringToTree = parse.scan -- for testing convenience


-- Interpreter function:

eval ::  ParseTree -> Double
eval (NumNode x) = x
-- not too sure if this would work
{- 
eval (OpNode c [p]) 
   | c == '/' = 1/p
   | c == '-' = -1 * p
-}   
eval (OpNode c pts) = foldl1 (charToFunction c) (map eval pts)

 functions here.
charToFunction :: Char -> (Double -> Double -> Double)
charToFunction '+' = (+)
charToFunction '-' = (-)
charToFunction '*' = (*)
charToFunction '/' = (/)
charToFunction _ = error "Invalid operator specified"

interpret :: String -> Double
interpret = eval.parse.scan
```

Answer (score 0):

The part you've commented out should work fine, except you need to `eval` the value `p`:

```
eval (OpNode c [p]) 
   | c == '/' = 1 / eval p
   | c == '-' = - eval p
eval (OpNode c pts) = foldl1 (charToFunction c) (map eval pts)
```

As a stylistic point, note that:

```
eval (OpNode '/' [p]) = 1 / eval p
eval (OpNode '-' [p]) = - eval p
...
```

might be more usual than using a guard with equalities.